# 'Error in .Call("add", a, b) : C symbol name "add" not in load table', Error when calling C functions from R

Tags: c, r

I was learning how to calling C functions from R by using ".Call()".
and I was following the example given [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html) .

I created a C file "add.c":

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>

SEXP add(SEXP a, SEXP b) {
  SEXP result = PROTECT(allocVector(REALSXP, 1));
  REAL(result)[0] = asReal(a) + asReal(b);
  UNPROTECT(1);

  return result;
}


$ R CMD SHLIB add.c
```

then I had:

```
add.c               
add.o               
add.so
```

created another R file "Calling_Cf_from_R_wrapper.R":

```
# In R ----------------------------------------
add <- function(a, b) {
  .Call("add", a, b)
}
```

within R session:

```
> source("Calling_Cf_from_R_wrapper.R")
> add(1,2)
Error in .Call("add", a, b) : C symbol name "add" not in load table
```

Any idea why it did not work out?
Thanks!

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi, yes! Worked. Could you put your comment as answer?  I guess  I could change the status of  the question as "accepted". Tsk!

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi,  never mind, just wanna give you credit you deserve. Tks!

Comment: The comment from ZheyuanLi seems to have vanished! How did you resolve this?